# Accessing precompiled handlebars templates for ember nested routes using gulp-handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, gulp

I am trying to access precompiled handlebars templates in the context of nested routes using gulp-handlebars

Given this simple route :

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() { // the `posts` route
    this.route('favorites');          // the `posts.favorites` route
  });
});
```

The `posts.hbs` template

```
 <div>
     Posts
     {{outlet}}
 </div>
```

The `posts.favorites.hbs` template

```
<div>Favorites</div>
```

Both of which reside in `app/templates`

Using the gulp task shown in the [documentation](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-handlebars/tree/master/examples/ember) I can successfully precompile the templates to `dist/templates.js`. e.g. the `posts.favorites` gets compiled to :

```
this["Ember"]["TEMPLATES"]["posts"]["favorites"] = Ember.Handlebars.template(function anonymous(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];
helpers = this.merge(helpers, Ember.Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};
  data.buffer.push("<div>Favorites</div>\n\n");
});
```

Letting Ember instantiate the controller and the route, I can successfully display `#/posts` but not `#/posts/favorites` because Ember looks for the `posts/favorites` template and not `posts.favorites`.

And if I manually change the precompiled `posts.favorites` template to : `this["Ember"]["TEMPLATES"]["posts/favorites"] = Ember.Handlebars.template(...)` then I can successfully display `#/posts/favorites`,

I would like to avoid having to specify the template manually and let EmberJS resolve it.

Is there any way of doing that save from changing the gulp task to post process the templates file ?

I am using EmberJS 1.8.1, handlebars 1.3.0 and gulp 3.8.10.